# Git commit 2 times

Tags: git, repository, git-commit

I have the following problem. I have two files a.txt and b.txt in my local Repository. I changed the name to a1.txt and b1.txt after that I added in each text document one word. 
After that I need to commit 2 times, the first commit is for changing the name of the text documents and the second commit after adding the words to the documents.
My Question is how can I do that?
What git commands would help me do so.

Comment: Make the first change commit it, and then make the second change and commit it

Comment: I don't see what the issue is or why you need 2 commits. If you want to do it in 2 commits you can, if you want to do it in 2 commits you can. Workflow is the same- standard commit procedure. Are you encountering any issues or...?

Answer (score 1):

Do it first:

> I have two files a.txt and b.txt in my local Repository. I changed the
>   name to a1.txt and b1.txt after that I added in each text document one
>   word.

Commit

Do it:

> I added in each text document one word

Commit again.

I think that is it.